# grep all those lines which have number "2" after 5th occurrence of "@"

Tags: perl, awk, grep

Please see the below output:

```
SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=IPRAN,MeContext=U207@10.218.131.141@5.5@15@ON@3@5@STN_NODE_MODEL@1389599874171@1389599874171
SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=IPRAN,MeContext=U201@10.218.132.161@5.8@15@ON@1@4@STN_NODE_MODEL@-1@-1
```

A file containing multiple lines like above. If you can see the different fields are above separated by "@" symbol. My intention is to select all those lines which number "3" after the 5th occurrence of "@" symbol.

Like from the above output, the result should be the below. Since it has number 3 after @ symbol occurred for five times.

```
SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=IPRAN,MeContext=U207@10.218.131.141@5.5@15@ON@3@5@STN_NODE_MODEL@1389599874171@1389599874171
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk -F@ '$6~/^3/'  yourfile
```

Note I wrote `~/^3/` because you just said 3 **after** the fifth `@`. I guess `3foobar` should be counted too.

If you want exact one char in column6, and it should be `3`,  you can change the line into `$6==3`

Comment: That's pretty clever, I was trying to loop through each one of the fields with `FS=""`... Great, +1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I have not understood the question, but I tested this solution

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @lines = ( 'SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=IPRAN,MeContext=U207@10.218.131.141@5.5@15@ON@3@5@STN_NODE_MODEL@1389599874171@1389599874171',
  'SubNetwork=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SubNetwork=IPRAN,MeContext=U201@10.218.132.161@5.8@15@ON@1@4@STN_NODE_MODEL@-1@-1');

foreach my $line (@lines) {
  my @parts = split ("@", $line);
  print $line if ($parts[5] =~ /^3$/);
}
```

[here](http://ideone.com/nTTIUa) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

6th field equal 3:

```
grep '^\([^@]*@\)\{5\}3@'    # POSIX regex

grep -P '^([^@]*@){5}3@'     # Perlish regex

perl -F@ -ane'print if $F[5] eq "3"'
```

---

6th field starts with 3:

```
grep '^\([^@]*@\)\{5\}3'    # POSIX regex

grep -P '^([^@]*@){5}3'     # Perlish regex

perl -F@ -ane'print if $F[5] =~ /^3/'
```

---

All of the above accept input from STDIN or from files named as arguments.